# eclipse indigo closes suddenly while editing my maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

eclipse indigo suddenly closes while editing my maven project.
tried editing eclipse ini file several times but could not find any answer
i put -XX:-UseCompressedOops  in the ini file according to stackoverflow but does not work.

this is the .log file stack trace printed

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2015-07-22 16:54:52.680
!MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
!STACK 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -10
at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:371)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getURLContents(JavaElement.java:786)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getJavadocContents(BinaryType.java:1037)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryMethod.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryMethod.java:643)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:621)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:567)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:559)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell since you haven't provided enough details regarding any stacktrace, errors, etc.

Comment: @kocko i have edited my question now